# Plotting high precision data as axis ticks or transforming it to different values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, precision

I am trying to plot some data as a histogram in matplotlib using a high precision values as x-axis ticks. The data is between 0 and 0.4, but most values are really close like:

> 0.05678, 0.05879, 0.125678, 0.129067

I used `np.around()` in order to make the values (and it made them as it should from 0 to 0.4) less but it didn't work quite right for all of the data.
Here is an example of the one that worked somewhat right ->

[image]

and one that didn't ->[image]

you can see there are points after 0.4 which is just not right. 
Here is the code I used in `Jupyter Notebook`:

```
plt.hist(x=[advb_ratios,adj_ratios,verb_ratios],color = ['r','y','b'], bins =10, label = ['adverbs','adjectives', 'verbs'])
plt.xticks(np.around(ranks,1))
plt.xlabel('Argument Rank')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

It is the same for both histograms only different `x` that I am plotting, all `x` values that are used are between `0 and 1`.

**So my questions are:**

1. Is there a way to fix that and reflect my data as it is?
2. Is it better to give my `rank` values different labels that will separate them more from one another for example - 1,2,3,4 or I will lose the precision of my data and some useful info?
3. What is the general approach in such situations? Would a different graphic help? What?

Comment: Would scaling the data just for ploting it be an option? Using 56.78 and 58.79 for example instead..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your problem, the fact that you data is between 0 and 0.4 should not influence the way it is displayed. I don't see why you need to do anything else but call `plt.hist()`.

In addition, you can pass an array to the `bins` argument to indicate which bins you want, so you could do something like that to force the size of your bins to be always the same

```
# Fake data
x1 = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.1, size=(1000,))
x2 = np.random.normal(loc=0.2, scale=0.1, size=(1000,))
x3 = np.random.normal(loc=0.4, scale=0.1, size=(1000,))

plt.hist([x1,x2,x3], bins=np.linspace(0,0.4,10))
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that all values are really close to each other and if I don't do np.around() the x axis is shown as a black line, and on the second graphic that I have shown you can see how there are bins after 0.4, tho your answer partially clears the things up. But what if I want to use my ranks array as the xticks how can I still force it like this? I mean let suppose I don't know how the range varies?